# Allow users to upload multiple images to their profile

Tags: images, uploads, profiles

I've asked this before but to no avail.

I need the ability for any user (From Contributor up) of my website to upload a minimum of 5 and a maximum of 10 images to their profile and have they displayed immediately

I'm sure there's a way to customize the User Photo plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/ but it's beyond my skillset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) which will allow you to add as many fields as you'd like and currently supports:

- text
- textarea
- textarea-rich
- password
- checkbox
- radio
- drop-down
- picture
- picture-url
- registration-date
- avatar
- **file**

Comment: Perfect, thanks man. Now I just need to work it so users can upload images from within the template without having to go into the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

There's also the Pro version for [Profile Builder](http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/) that has the same functionality (file upload that is).